# How many time access to email app

Tags: java, android, android-service, usagestatsmanager, usageevents

I need to know from my app how many times in a day I access to email app, and I need to know when I launch email app.

I have found usage stat and event usage, but any solution allowed me to solve my problem.

Thanks

Comment: This isn't possible.  Android doesn't have a concept of "an email app".  Unless you know the name of every email app out there, you couldn't even begin this.

Comment: Of course, it was just an example. For example gmail

Comment: You can use `UsageEvents` to accomplish this, please have a look here, where a solution is shown https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46650520/count-how-many-times-every-app-is-used-in-one-day-using-usageevents-usageevents (I have not personally tested it).